# Stokes' theorem without the smoothness condition

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I think I have proved the following version of Stokes' theorem:

**Teorem 1**: Let $\beta: [0,4] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the curve given by
\begin{equation}
  \beta(t) =
\begin{cases}
  (t,0) & \mbox{if } t\in[0,1], \\
  (1,t-1) & \mbox{if } t\in[1,2], \\
  (3-t,1) & \mbox{if } t\in[2,3], \\
  (0,4-t) & \mbox{if } t\in[3,4].
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This is the boundary of the square $D = [0,1] \times [0,1]$, oriented counterclockwise with speed 1. Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set containing $D$. If $\sigma: A \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is of class $C^2$, $\vec{F}: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is of class $C^1$ and $\alpha = \sigma \circ \beta$, then
\begin{equation}\label{E:Stokes}
  \int_{\alpha} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_\sigma \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}. 
\end{equation}

Apparently, I didn't need the usual hypothesis that $\sigma$ is a *piecewise smooth* parametrized surface. Is it in fact possible? Or I must have made some mistake?

**Edit**: My definition of the surface integral above is:
$$ \iint_\sigma \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_D \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F}(\sigma(u,v)) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial u}(u,v) \times \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial v}(u,v) \right) \,dA. $$
And the smoothness condition is this:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothSurface.html

Comment: How is the boundary NOT a piecewise smooth parametrized surface.

Comment: @William, what?

Comment: well $\beta$ is clearly piecewise smooth, $\sigma$ is $C^2$, so where is the non-smooth surface?

Comment: @William, by definition, $\sigma$ is smooth if $\lVert \sigma_u \times \sigma_v \rVert$ is always nonzero. I did not suppose this.

Comment: Similarly, $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is piecewise smooth it it can be covered by finitely many smooth parametrizations.

Comment: The first condition only deals with whether or not $\sigma$ has any critical points; it has nothing to do with the differentiability of the parametrization.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothSurface.html

Comment: So, do you think Theorem 1 is correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448979/what-is-a-smooth-surface
I'm not an expert in differential geometry, but my guess would be that it is correct. As far as I can tell, the extra condition in the Wolfram definition only deals with the regularity of the points of the surface, not whether or not they are smooth. The function $\sigma$ is $C^2$, that is usually sufficiently smooth.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think that condition serves only for motivating the definition of the surface integral. Because it enables us to define a normal unitary vector field on the surface. But every calculus book assumes that condition in the statement of Stokes' theorem.

Comment: What do you mean "every" book? I haven't seen the condition in any statement of the theorem before. And it certainly doesn't seem to appear in the general formulation: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StokesTheorem.html

Comment: By "every book" I mean the Stewart's Calculus and other similar books about differential and integral Calculus. Yes, it is an abuse of language.

Comment: It might make sense to post a new question specifically addressing what the proper definition of "smooth surface" is for Stokes' Theorem -- it would answer your question, and be more likely to get an answer from a knowledgeable expert (e.g. not me) because it would be more generally applicable.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798916/is-sigma-u-times-sigma-v-neq-vec0-essential-for-int-alpha-vecf

Comment: This question was answered here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798916/is-sigma-u-times-sigma-v-neq-vec0-essential-for-int-alpha-vecf