# Is $\sigma_u \times \sigma_v \neq \vec{0}$ essential for $\int_{\alpha} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_\sigma \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I think I have proved the following version of Stokes' theorem:

**Teorem 1**: Let $\beta: [0,4] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the curve given by
\begin{equation}
  \beta(t) =
\begin{cases}
  (t,0) & \mbox{if } t\in[0,1], \\
  (1,t-1) & \mbox{if } t\in[1,2], \\
  (3-t,1) & \mbox{if } t\in[2,3], \\
  (0,4-t) & \mbox{if } t\in[3,4].
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This is the boundary of the square $D = [0,1] \times [0,1]$, oriented counterclockwise with speed 1. Suppose $\sigma: D \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is extensible to a function of class $C^2$ on an open set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ containing $D$. If $\vec{F}: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is of class $C^1$ and $\alpha = \sigma \circ \beta$, then
\begin{equation}\label{E:Stokes}
  \int_{\alpha} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_\sigma \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}. 
\end{equation}

Apparently, I didn't need the usual hypothesis that $\sigma$ is a regular (or [smooth](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothSurface.html)) surface, in a sense that
$$ \left\lVert \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial u}(u,v) \times \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial v}(u,v) \right\rVert \neq 0$$
for all $(u,v) \in D$. Is it in fact possible? Or must I have made some mistake?

Comment: You're correct, except that the integral needs to be over $\sigma(D)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin My definition of that surface integral is:  
$$\iint_\sigma \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_D \mathrm{curl}\,\vec{F}(\sigma(u,v)) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial u}(u,v) \times \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial v}(u,v) \right) \,dA.$$

Comment: But note that your domain of $\sigma$ is the open set $A$. It should be $D$, with the appropriate notion of $C^2$ extension to a larger open set.

Comment: Yeeees, you're right! I had not noticed this detail.

Comment: The domain of $\sigma$ is now corrected.